# how to get icmp(ping) target ip addr by using "golang.org/x/net/icmp"

Tags: go, ping, icmp

I have a icmp listening func :

```
func Start(url string) {

conn, err := icmp.ListenPacket("ip4:icmp", url)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

for {
    var msg []byte
    length, sourceIP, err := conn.ReadFrom(msg)

    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        continue
    }
    fmt.Println(url + "===========")
    log.Printf("message = '%s', length = %d, source-ip = %s", string(msg), length, sourceIP)
}
_ = conn.Close()

}
```

because of there are **two network cards** in my server host,  I start this func with "**Start(0.0.0.0)**",

at the time of ping to this server,  got the following information:

```
2020/08/31 11:11:02 message = '', length = 0, source-ip = 192.168.255.133
192.168.255.128===========
2020/08/31 11:11:03 message = '', length = 0, source-ip = 192.168.255.133
192.168.255.128===========
2020/08/31 11:11:04 message = '', length = 0, source-ip = 192.168.255.133
```

Source ip address only , how to get ping target ip addr?